# Reserve space for invisible items in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to animate an image and a text field in my News App.
I want the Icon to appear first and after a few seconds the text.

The problem that I am facing is that when the icon loads(first) then it is in the absolute center and when text becomes visible, the icon shifts a little bit upwards. I want to stop this shift of the icon which was loaded first.

Or more precisely, how can I allocate space for an invisible item on screen?

Here is my Code:

```
@Composable
fun SplashScreen(
    navController: NavController
){
    var imageVisibility by remember{
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    var textVisibility by remember{
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    LaunchedEffect(Unit){
        delay(1000)
        imageVisibility = true
        delay(5000)
        textVisibility = true
        delay(5000)
        navController.navigate(Destinations.HomeScreen.route)
    }


    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ){
        Column{
            AnimatedVisibility(
                visible = imageVisibility,
                enter = fadeIn(
                    TweenSpec(
                        durationMillis = 3000
                    )
                )
            ) {
                Image(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.news_splash_screen),
                    contentDescription = "News Splash Screen"
                )
            }
            AnimatedVisibility(
                visible = textVisibility,
                enter = fadeIn(
                    TweenSpec(
                        durationMillis = 3000
                    )
                )
            ){
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    text = "Read News Everyday",
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `animateFloatAsState` to animate `alpha`, instead of `AnimatedVisibility` for the `Text`.

Sample code,

```
@Composable
fun SplashScreen(
    navHostController: NavController,
) {
    var imageVisibility by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    var textVisibility by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        delay(1000)
        imageVisibility = true
        delay(5000)
        textVisibility = true
        delay(5000)
        // navHostController.navigate("second")
    }
    val alpha: Float by animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = if (textVisibility) {
            1f
        } else {
            0f
        },
        animationSpec = tween(
            durationMillis = 3000,
            easing = LinearEasing,
        ),
    )

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Column {
            AnimatedVisibility(
                visible = imageVisibility,
                enter = fadeIn(
                    TweenSpec(
                        durationMillis = 3000
                    )
                )
            ) {
                Image(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_background),
                    contentDescription = "News Splash Screen"
                )
            }
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .alpha(
                        alpha = alpha,
                    ),
                text = "Read News Everyday",
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Video]

Comment: Thank you! It really helped. There is one thing I want to ask that I tried using alpha using in textAlpha inside text composable and it was giving me errors whereas alpha in modifier worked perfectly fine, why so?

Comment: Note that if you do this with clickable composable such as button, they still can be clicked

Comment: @Abhimanyu I think that error is no longer there.